How to wait for Redux reducer actions to finish before navigating to another page?
I'm trying to dispatch some Redux actions in the cleanup function of a React component's useEffect (during unmount) and ensure these actions are completed before navigating to another page. The actions are simple reducers (synchronous), and they look like this:
const mySlice = createSlice({
    name: 'mySlice',
    initialState: {
        items: [],
        details: {}
    },
    reducers: {
        clearItems: (state) => {
            return {
                ...state,
                items: []
            };
        },
        clearDetails: (state) => {
            return {
                ...state,
                details: {}
            };
        }
    }
});

export const { clearItems, clearDetails } = mySlice.actions;

In the component, I am trying to clear the Redux state on unmount and then navigate to a different page:
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { clearItems, clearDetails } from './mySlice';

const MyComponent = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            dispatch(clearItems());
            dispatch(clearDetails());
            // I want to wait for these to complete before navigating to another page/completing the unmount
        };
    }, []);

    return <div>My Component</div>;
};

export default MyComponent;

How can I achieve this?

clearItems and clearDetails are synchronous reducers, i.e. they are sent and handled immediately
There's no need to wait for them to end explicitly, as the Redux state is updated synchronously

Redux reducers are pure, synchronous functions, so there is nothing to wait for, they immediately update the store. What have you tried already? Is there a problem or something not working as you expect? Please [edit] to clarify your question and provide more complete details.
